# caret position of an embedded swing component in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, caret, htmleditorkit

I have a JTextPane which uses a custom HTMLEditorKit to embed a swing component when the  HTML tag is used.  When I click on this component, I want to have the caret position updated to the location of this component.  I can get the focus event in the control, but I don't know how to set the caret position to the location of this component.  Anyone know how?

Comment: [please search in answers by @StanislavL](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A301607+[jtextpane])

Comment: @mKorbel thank you, but I don't remember I answered similar question:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get clicked component's parent and use `parent.getBounds()`. The rectangle returned is the position in `JTextPane`. The use `viewToModel()` method of `JTextPane` to get caret position for the coordinates location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the character position of the embedded component within the JTextPane's content; without more details, there's no way to guess how you would determine that. However, once you know the character position of the component, it's as easy as:

```
myTextPane.setCaretPosition(characterIndexOfEmbeddedComponent);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)